# Add arguments to a IronPython CallExpression

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm walking over Python code with a `PythonWalker`. From the `bool Walk(CallExpression node)` method I want to add a argument to the call if it meets certain critieras.
The `node.Args` is readonly and the property has no setter.

If PythonWalker are read only how do I alter code using IronPytjons PythonAst?

I'm using IronPython 2.7.x